# Confused by behaviour of NSBundle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbundle

I've a plist file that sits in a directory called Templates of my .app directory. This plist file is loaded thus without any problems:

```
NSDictionary *sqlPropertyList = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:CH_PQ_QUERIES ofType:@"plist"]];
```

I created a .txt file in the same directory and tried to load it the same way:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"excel2004" ofType:@"xml"];
```

But `filePath` was always null, even though the bundled appeared to be loaded.

What's going on here? Why are plists allowed to sit in subdirectories and other files not? Is the plist file being loaded by accident and I shouldn't rely on this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: What’s the value of CH_PQ_QUERIES? Did you clean the project before testing if the plist loading works? There might be an older copy of the plist file still lying around in your app wrapper.

Comment: A `.txt` file or `.xml` file?

Comment: An XML file that I'm reading as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a silly question, but you say you created a "txt" file but your call to `pathToResource:ofType:` specifies `xml` as the type. Is that correct? And, of course, any files like these need to be in the `Resources` directory of your app bundle.